# Enumeration Type-Safety in D

Tags: casting, enums, d, enumeration, type-safety

What is the state and plans on type-safety of enums in D?

I expected

```
import std.stdio: writeln;

void main(string args[]) {
    enum E {x, y, z}
    E e;
    writeln(e);
    e = cast(E)3;
    writeln(e);
}
```

to fail to compile because of D's otherwise strong static type/range checking or at least give an RangeException when run.

To my surprise, it instead prints

```
cast(E)3
```

Is this really the preferred default behaviour for the majority of use cases? If so have anybody written some wrapper type providing more stricter range-checking preferrably in compile-time?

Comment: enums are often also used as flags and `cast` is a flag that some things may not pass correctly and return odd values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cast` means you're taking matters into your own hands, and you can do anything with it - useful, like ratchet freak said, for combining flags. (Though, in those cases, I like to give an exact type and explicit values to each item to be sure everything does what I want, so enum : ubyte { x = 1, y = 2, z = 4}, that kind of thing)

Anyway, there is a way to get runtime exceptions though in a case like this: use std.conv.to:

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    enum E {x, y, z}
    E e;
    writeln(e);
    e = to!E(2); // gives z, whereas to!E(3) throws an exception
    writeln(e);
}
```

Cool fact: to!E(string) also works. to!E("x") == E.x, and to!string(E.x) == "x".

Comment: One quick test later: No, it does not. :p

Comment: The way to!enum(string) and vice versa is implemented relates to the other question about enum reflection: they check the allMembers strings, so it is a nice whitelist there. (speaking of whitelists, I actually use enums in my webapps for this: my web.d can build <select> things out of an enum definition automatically, and then it automatically checks user data to ensure it is on that list. Pretty convenient and nice for web security too!)